# jQuery Mobile ajax-loaded links break on refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

By default, when you click on a link in jQuery mobile, the click is intercepted and page is loaded via Ajax.  However, the browser location is pointing to the link.

Usually linked pages in jQuery mobile contain only the mobile page DOM and nothing else, since it is meant to be injected into a parent page.  This means that the site is broken if you refresh the page after you select an ajax-loaded link.

Is there any way around this? Perhaps using hashtags in the browser location rather than pointing to the actual page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to this, the two simplest ones being :

- have a single multipage file, and use hashtags to navigate within it with jquery mobile
- if you want to keep separate files, you will have to ensure that all your pages have all the links to scripts, css in their headers, as well as any initialization. This way the proper resources will be available even if you refresh your page

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm thinking of what you suggested i.e. a single multipage file, but what other approaches did you have in mind?